# Storing data in Azure for plotting

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage

I use service bus topic to send message from emulated device (temperature, timestamp).
I save the received data into blob storage in JSON format using Azure functions. I want to build plots later.
However I think that there's a better way to store the data. Cosmos DB or any?
Could anybody advice please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can easily store the data in a SQL Azure database (or a SQL Azure Data Warehouse) in order to plot the timeseries.